# Programmatically adding to autocomplete in Firefox and Edge not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

I want to add a text input value to a browser's autocomplete data store programmatically in JavaScript (no jQuery) via a function attached to a 'button' input element.  The code below all worked fine for some time, and now (maybe for a while, just no one noticed) has stopped working in Firefox and Edge.

```js
function addToAutoComplete(inputElementId) {

    // Get a reference to the input element whose name/value
    // we want added to the browser's autocomplete data
    var inputEl = document.getElementById(inputElementId);

    // Create an iframe window, and append to the document body (temporarily)
    var iFrameEl = document.createElement('iframe');
    iFrameEl.id = 'iFrameEl';
    iFrameEl.src = 'about:blank';
    document.body.appendChild(iFrameEl);

    // Create a form element 
    var frameForm = document.createElement('form');
    frameForm.id = 'FormEl';
    frameForm.method = "post";
    frameForm.autocomplete = "on";

    // Append the form element inside the iframe body
    var iFrameWindow = iFrameEl.contentWindow;
    iFrameWindow.document.body.appendChild(frameForm);

    // Append a clone of the input element to the form element
    frameForm.appendChild(inputEl.cloneNode(true));

    // Submit the form in the iframe, so that the input element value 
    // is stored in the browser's autocomplete data
    frameForm.onsubmit = null;
    frameForm.submit();

    // Remove the temporary iframe 
    document.body.removeChild(iFrameEl);
}
```

This works fine in Chrome.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not posted your HTML code so I am not sure whether you had used **autocomplete="on"** attribute in your code or not.

I suggest you to add **autocomplete="on"** in your textbox and also in your form like below. It makes it working for MS Edge and Firefox.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function addToAutoComplete() {

    // Get a reference to the input element whose name/value
    // we want added to the browser's autocomplete data
    var inputEl = document.getElementById("txt1");

    // Create an iframe window, and append to the document body (temporarily)
    var iFrameEl = document.createElement('iframe');
    iFrameEl.id = 'iFrameEl';
    iFrameEl.src = 'about:blank';
    document.body.appendChild(iFrameEl);

    // Create a form element 
    var frameForm = document.createElement('form');
    frameForm.id = 'FormEl';
    frameForm.method = "post";
    frameForm.autocomplete = "on";

    // Append the form element inside the iframe body
    var iFrameWindow = iFrameEl.contentWindow;
    iFrameWindow.document.body.appendChild(frameForm);

    // Append a clone of the input element to the form element
    frameForm.appendChild(inputEl.cloneNode(true));

    // Submit the form in the iframe, so that the input element value 
    // is stored in the browser's autocomplete data
    frameForm.onsubmit = null;
    frameForm.submit();

    // Remove the temporary iframe 
    document.body.removeChild(iFrameEl);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  autocomplete="on">
<label for="txt1">Add Value :</label> <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="" autocomplete="on" ><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="addToAutoComplete()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge browser:

[image]

Output in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  Yes, autocomplete is "on" in my HTML.  Your example HTML works fine in MS-Edge, though I still can't get it to work in Firefox 71.0.  :-(

Comment: You can try to add autocomplete="on" in your form tag and test.

Comment: Finally got it working in Firefox.  In my original HTML, the element whose 'click' event calls my JavaScript was an input element of type 'button'.  Changing this to 'submit' and cancelling the event in JavaScript via e.preventDefault() allows the Firefox 71.0 to work correctly.  Many thanks again for your response and your time.

Comment: From the last comment it looks like your issue is solved. I suggest you to mark the helpful answer as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding